# Difference between "Run" and "Run..." in IDE's?

Tags: python

In PyCharm (I assume other IDE's as well), when I press "run" in the taskbar, there are two options:

- Run (Shift f10)
- Run... (Alt Shift f10)

**What is the difference between these two?** I could not find this online.

ps. Is this the correct stackexchange site for this question? I didn't know which one fit best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift+Alt+F10 - Quickly select run/debug configuration and run/edit it.
Shift+F10 -     Run application.

This information is from: [PyCharm 2018.3 Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/shift.html)

But the question is totally and completely not about data-science.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ-based IDEs (and PyCharm is one of them):

- **Run** will run the last run command you executed successfully, be this an invocation of `main` or a test, or whatever PyCharm executed on your behalf.
- **Run...** will allow you to select a *previously* run command or previously configured command to run (see Edit Configurations) without it necessarily being the last thing you ran.

Note that this is distinct and separate from debugging.  Both debug commands have the same convention as the Run commands, and both do effectively the same thing with the difference in being that the debugger will be attached in a debug context.